# Jquery click on generated divs with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys i am new to jQuery and I have struggled with no success to solve this problem. I try to generate some divs with the following code and I want to make them clickable so when anyone clicks on them, the background becomes red.

Here is the jquery code which generates the div

```
function drawCanvas(){
    var divHeight = 4;
    var counter = 0;
    for (var j =0; j <6; j++){
        for(var i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++){
           var left = j*105;
           var top  = i *105;                  
           $("#area").append("<div class='tile' style='height:100px; width:100px; position:absolute; top:"+top+"px; left:"+left+"px; border:1px solid black;  '></div> ");                
        }               
    }
}


$("#canvasSubmit").click(function(){
    var radioValue = $("input[name='optionsRadios']:checked").val();
    if(radioValue == 1){
        $("#area").width(600);
        $("#area").height(400);
        drawCanvas();
    }   
    else if(radioValue == 2){
        $("#area").width(600);
        $("#area").height(600);
    }
    if(radioValue == 3){
         $("#area").width(900);
         $("#area").height(600);
    }
});
```

and here is what I have tried so far with no success

```
$(this).find(".tile").click(function(i){
    $(this).addClass("red"); 
});
```

and here using `on()` but it is also not working

```
$(".tile").on("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass("red"); 
});
```

Can you please help me???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Your listener should look like:

```
$('#area').on('click', '.tile', function() {
    $(this).addClass('red');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be fine, you just need to have a CSS class for the ".red" class you are adding. Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/madkidflash/bjmpqn4t/

CSS Area:

```
.red { background-color: red; }
```

You can also toggle the class if that is more useful.

```
$(".tile").click(function(i){
    $(this).toggleClass("red");
});
```

Revised Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/madkidflash/bjmpqn4t/2/

Comment: Your example uses the ```drawCanvas()``` function on wrong context. The tiles will create at a form submit. Your fiddle draws the canvas on load. For dynamic created objects you must use event delegation.

Comment: The question was posed as to how to make a div's background red by adding a class when said div was clicked. How the drawCanvas() function is invoked is irrelevant.